# XSL: split string into tags based on regex

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, substring, xslt-2.0

I'm working in XSLT 2.0 and having trouble wrapping tags around parts of a string. Here's what I've got:

```
<dc:subject>Red&#xD;
            Green&#xD;
            Blue
</dc:subject>
```

and desired output:

```
<subject>
  <topic>Red</topic>
  <topic>Green</topic>
  <topic>Blue</topic>
</subject>
```

I know I can use `substring-before()` to grab anything before the divider, but I don't know how to use it recursively to get *each* instance before the divider; on the other hand, since I'm in 2.0 I can use `replace()` to hit all occurrences, but it won't accept an angle bracket so I can't just tell it to wrap each occurrence in the `<topic>` tags. What am I missing here?

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(dc:subject, '.*&#xD;','????')"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(dc:subject, '&#xD;')"/>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new nodes here, so it is not the right approach to use `replace` which is purely about replacing strings with other strings.

You can use `tokenize` here to split the string, and then use `xsl:for-each` to create your new `topic` for each part

```
<subject>
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(dc:subject, '&#xD;')">
     <topic>
       <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
     </topic>
  </xsl:for-each>
</subject>
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew `for-each` couldn't be used on strings as such, but I didn't think of `tokenize`. Thank you! I'll follow up if I find any more problems with implementing this.